# Google analytics script not found while checking SEO

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, elementor, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

```js
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-TWEZSMMQHV"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-TWEZSMMQHV');
</script>
```

This is the code that I'm using in elementor that I got from Google Analytics. I'm using the insert headers and footers plugin to put the code and have already pasted it in the head section of it. I even tried through the custom code that elementor provides. Can someone please look into it and lemme know why it's being detected, even the source code has the code....

Comment: What does the rest of the site look like? Where did you insert the Google analytics script?

Comment: The site looks fine and I have put the script in the insert headers & footers plugin where we can insert scripts in header footer or body

Comment: i can see the script when im using the google script check plugin for chrome but it shows no script on seositecheckup.com. the site is amplispot.com